# Map of Map data struct confusion

Tags: c++

I am trying to setup a map of map structure in C++ but can't make it work as expected. I put together this sample program to illustrate the issue. Please excuse the mess if it seems convoluted but I want to preserve the case as much as I can.

So the current print out is: `L1, size = 0`
and what I was expecting is something like:

```
L1, size 1
   L2, 4
```

It seems like the second level map is *not* established properly, maybe a scoping issue, but I can't quite figure it out. The program is as the following:

```
// So the map is
// AKEY -> { BKEY -> [ SegPair, SegPair  .... ] }

#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::string AKEY;
typedef std::string BKEY;

typedef std::pair<int,int> SegPair;
typedef std::vector<SegPair> SegVec;
typedef std::map<BKEY, SegVec> Ensemble;
typedef std::map<AKEY, Ensemble> Oracle;

using std::string;

Oracle o = Oracle();

void setup(string akey, string bkey, int x, int y) {
    auto pos = o.find(akey);
    if (pos == o.end()) {
        o[akey] = Ensemble();
    }

    Ensemble e = o[akey];

    auto pos2 = e.find(bkey);
    if (pos2 == e.end()) {
        e[bkey] = SegVec();
    }

    SegPair p(x, y);
    e[bkey].push_back(p);
}

int main(void) {

    setup("L1", "L2", 3, 4);

    for (auto it = o.begin(); it != o.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << it->first;
        Ensemble e = it->second;
        std::cout << ", size = " << e.size() << "\n";
        for (auto it2 = e.begin(); it2 != e.end(); it2++) {
            std::cout << "\t" << it2-> first << "\n";
            SegVec v = it2->second;
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                std::cout<< v[i].second << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: modify ` Ensemble e = o[akey];` to ` Ensemble& e = o[akey];`. By taking the reference you will modify the o[key]. Right now you are modifying the copy of o[key] I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with this line:

```
Ensemble e = o[akey];
```

You're creating a local, rather than capturing the lvalue in the map by reference, for mutation.  Thus, any changes you make to e after that point will simply be discarded when e goes out of scope.

Comment: @Oliver `Ensemble &e = o[akey];`

Comment: yes, thanks for both (Scotty and gonzhitaao) for pointing out the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In `setup`, `e` is a *copy* of the object in `o`.
When you modify it, you're not modifying anything in `o`.

To fix, use a *reference*:

```
Ensemble& e = o[akey];
```

That will make `e` refer to the same thing as `o[akey]` instead of a copy.